# Where can one find completed and processed Hi-C datasets?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna, theoretical-biology, 3d-structure

I and a statistics graduate student at UCR, and I am working on Optimal Binning schemes and peak detection in Hi-C data analysis (a dataset that conveys information about proximity of a DNA strand with itself *within* the nucleus).  I am **not** a bioinformatician, so I am looking for someone that already has some complete data, or a website that may have these available for download.  The more datasets, the better.

Can anyone help me?  If you provide the data yourself, I will be sure to mention you in the foreword to my dissertation.

Thanks!

P.S.  If someone can find data generated specifically by the program "Hi-C Pro" with *"allele specific analysis,"* I would be *doubly* grateful.